# EACCESS Permission denied on SSL certificate files when starting Phoenix production server

Tags: ssl, https, elixir, phoenix-framework, lets-encrypt

I have added some fresh Let's Encrypt SSL certificates to my Phoenix app as described in the guide here: https://phoenixframework.readme.io/docs/configuration-for-ssl

When I try to start my server in production mode I get the following error:

```
23:04:11.573 [info] Running MyAppWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://:::4000
23:04:11.652 [error] Failed to start Ranch listener MyAppWeb.Endpoint.HTTPS in :ranch_ssl:listen([certfile: '/Users/FJ/projects/elixir/my_app/_build/prod/lib/my_app/priv/ssl/cert.crt', keyfile: '/Users/FJ/projects/elixir/my_app/_build/prod/lib/my_app/priv/ssl/priv.key', port: 443]) for reason :eacces (permission denied)
```

I don't understand why this happens because I have given the files pretty much all read permissions possible:

```
ls -la priv/ssl/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 FJ  staff   128 Apr 25 23:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x  9 FJ  staff   288 Apr 25 23:09 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 FJ  staff  1708 Apr 25 23:02 cert.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 FJ  staff  1708 Apr 25 23:03 priv.key
```

I am using MacOS locally but in my production environment (Alpine Linux) I the same error.

Here is the SSL part of production Endpoint config:

```
  https: [port: 443,
        otp_app: :my_app,
        keyfile: "priv/ssl/priv.key",
        certfile: "priv/ssl/cert.crt"
        ]
```

Comment: “I have given the files pretty much all read permissions possible”—that could be an issue. Please try to `chown` to the user _running the webserver_ (this is possibly you, so, ok,) and `chmod` to `600`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for your comment! I tried that but it got the same results. What I meant to say with that quote is that I actually incrementally increased the permissions on the files as I kept getting that error again and again.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with the cert files and not with opening a port under 1000 without running the app as root? Since running as root is problematic, usually you'll use something as nginx (in production) but locally I have no idea on a good solution though

Comment: @m3characters I have tried running it as root in my production setting and also tried to run the server locally with sudo while also giving ownage of the files to root. The error was still the same. It seems likely that the error does not show the real issue since it does not make sense. I guess will have to start digging around the Phoenix source code.

Comment: @Fabian - not sure then - I had run into this situation (or a very similar one) where the error came from binding to a lower port (443) hence the comment, good luck